# Vulgar wedding situation

Tags: wordplay

There was a wedding. When the right time came, the bride elbowed the groom, and he said, loud and clear, "Asshole". The officiant nodded and continued with the ceremony. Perhaps only the groom's parents could have been a bit amused, but not really.

At the end, everyone was happy, such as weddings usually go.

How is this possible? (edited - better wording)

Hint:

> This really happened. It's a bit silly, but a nice example how real life situations can create unintended riddles. There is some leeway in the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is potentially a good story/pun/whatever, but this is not a puzzle. It is a "guess what happend" situation - and people are guessing. Could also be VTC as "too broad" or "speculative" etc. But I wanted to add an explaination instead.

Comment: @BmyGuest - Aren't most riddles/lateral thinking puzzles/etc like that? You're given just a small part of the necessary information and need to guess the rest?

Comment: @Vilx Judgement of quality & suitability is to a large extend subjective and often *impossisble* to frame into solid rules. That's why this is based on *voting*. To my taste, posts like this cross the line towards "Just guess", but others might disagree. I'm certainly not "policing" this site - I'm online far too rarely these days - but comparing "puzzles" like this post to "puzzles" I have seen on the site and would like to see more of on this site, make me casting my vote. If 90% of posts on site would be like this, I wouldn't bother to come here anymore. This is an *opinion*.

Comment: @BmyGuest - I see. Fair enough. :)

Comment: @BmyGuest well, IMHO, it *is* a puzzle - based on wordplay, a simple one, with an easy answer if you happen to posses certain (general knowledge) information, less easy if you do not. That it happened IRL is a bonus (otherwise the hint would be something like "it is about a situation that could hypothetically happen")

Comment: @RadovanGarabík - maybe a `knowledge` tag, then?

Comment: @vlix No. Good riddles would have sufficient information for you to know that your answer is correct. I don't think this puzzle has enough information to make sure that one answer is the " obvious correct" answer

Comment: @Sid I think there is enough information, if you know certain facts (it's not *common* knowledge, but nothing obscure either - saying anything more would be an enormous hint)

Comment: @Phylyp perhaps... anyway, my original plan was to wait a little and release another hint in form of a tag (which would make obvious the direction of the answer), but nevertheless, such an answer (in the intended way, but unfinished) has already appeared....

Comment: You shouldn't hold back tags because they might spoil the answer. If it is not 'common knowledge' or if another language is involved and you don't tell us about it, it is an unfair puzzle or afwully close to (https://xkcd.com/169/)

Comment: @Sid consider the fact that all the presented "not intended" answers violated the premises in this or that minor point, while the "intended" answer did not. I take it as a proof that the question was not underspecified. That's, however, just my opinion and I am not going to re-open the question. RIP.

Answer (score 3):

I reckon

> the groom suffers from [Tourette's syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourette_syndrome), displaying the tic of [coprolalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprolalia). No one was bothered because it can be naturally assumed that everyone present at the ceremony was aware of the groom's condition and hence took no undue notice of it.

Comment: Could be, but 1) his parents (not other people present) might have been concerned (and one would expect the parents to be used to their son's syndrome) and 2) the ceremony continued right after he said this

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

> they speak in another language where 'Asshole' mean 'I love you' or 'Yes, i want' or any other sentence that would perfectly makes sence in a wedding

Comment: Or "I do" in such a language

Comment: The answer would, of course, include the name of the language...

Comment: So, which variant of 'Yes/I do/Certainly/Of course/I will/etc' sounds most like 'Asshole' in any possible language. Shouldn't be that hard right?

Comment: @PL457 exactly  - it's  not that hard, even if you happen not to speak the language(s) in question (there are some more possibilities).  This answer is correct at the first approximation, though it lacks a certain logical extension (I'd accept it even without naming the language, if it had the conclusion). And, to get the language, there is an important background hint that went unnoticed...

Answer (score 2):

> The groom was a little on the deaf side and unfamiliar with English.When the time came to be asked Do you take this woman to be your bride?   he misheard this as Where do you take this woman who is to be your bride and gave his answer for where he planned ...

Comment: We've got kids on this site! :-)

Comment: @Phylyp Nah. You have to be over 13 to be on this site(at least legally)

Comment: Hilarious (and it could have been a same-sex wedding), but no - "The officiant nodded and continued" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be that

> They wrote each other's vows and the bride's for the groom included something along the lines of "I vow not be an asshole" which the officiant read to the groom and the groom had to repeat, possibly stumbling over the word.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> The officiant had just asked if anyone had any objections to the wedding, and one of the groom's friends stood up and gave an objection that was very clearly a joke. The bride nudged the groom to get him to shut his friend up, and the groom promptly (and jokingly) called his friend an asshole. Since nobody had any actual objections, the ceremony continued.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Either the groom or the bride actually has the surname (or name?) "Asshole". Unusual, but possible. Or perhaps one of them has a name that is pronounced very similar, like "Asole". Most likely the groom, since it was his parents that could have reacted.

Comment: Yes, like in "Meet the Fockers". I considered narrowing it down to explicitly exclude this possibility, but I think if this were the case, everyone *else* but his parents would be caught by the word - supposedly, they'd be well accustomed to it...

Comment: [Surrounded by them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqYnyI0nRYI)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík - Good point. OK, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Separatrix - that movie, it's got a joke for every occasion!

Comment: @Phylyp - One of these days I'll have to watch it. :D

Answer (score 1):

> Asshole could have been *a soul* and thus no harm was done...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe......

> He is actually **sneezing**...... :|
>
>  *achoo*, well, sounds like *asshole*......

Comment: He said it "loud and clear"

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> **As hold**

but

> misheard to be Asshole :D